# Overlap images preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a preview image before upload. When I choose new images the code doesn't delete the old ones before appending. When I choose new images I want to delete the old ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
      if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;
        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(event) {
            $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
      }
    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
      imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" class="chooseFile">

<div class="gallery">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can simply call `empty()` on the container where you append the images.

Also note that the logic you use to loop through, process and append the images can be made more succinct. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
    $(placeToInsertImagePreview).empty();
    
    Array.from(input.files).forEach(file => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => $('<img>').prop('src', e.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };

  $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" class="chooseFile">

<div class="gallery"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `$('.gallery').empty();` before you call `imagesPreview(..)`.

```
$('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
  $('.gallery').empty();
  imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the async filereader to read images as base64, you will only waste processing & memory. Use [ObjectURLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead that can create a references point to the blob/file

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
    $(placeToInsertImagePreview).empty()
    
    Array.from(input.files).forEach(file => {
      $('<img>', {
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      }).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview)
    })
  }

  $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" class="chooseFile">

<div class="gallery"></div>
```